# SharePoint Standard 2013, FIM sync service keeps disabling

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service

We have a SharePoint 2013 farm - single server and we are trying to start the UPS service etc.

When we try to start the:

Forefront Identity Manage Synchronisation Service

It just says starting and stays like that for some time and then stops.

Do you have any ideas on this.

Comment: You need to check the ULS logs and Event log for more clue, their should be some error, please share with us so that we can guide you

Answer (score 0):

It is almost always permissions that cause UPS issues.

When you start it the user profile service and the user profile sync service you must be using a farm admin account and be a local administrator.

Also check that you have configured the sync service to use the Farm account as the service account, and it is a member of the local admins group (you can remove once it's started).

Once it starts - reset IIS.

If you are running SharePoint backups - part of the process will stop the services.  If you have removed the Farm account from the local admins group the service will not start correctly and stop, until you add it in there and manually restart the services.

If the above doesn't help - I recommend you go back thru step by step like you were setting up a new service and validate permissions and configuration for each account and service.